# Eigenvector of $A$ and $(I-A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$A\in \mathbb {R}^{n\times n}$, $\|A\|<1$, and $\vec b\in \mathbb {R}^{n}$. If $\vec b$ is the eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to the largest eigenvelue, which is $0<\lambda<1$. Is is possible for $\vec b$ to be the eigenvector of $(I-A)$ corresponding to the largest eigenvalue?

Comment: This is true if and only if the only $A$ has only one eigenvalue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Just take $A=\lambda\operatorname{Id}$.

Comment: Thank you, sir. And is this the only possibility?

Comment: It depends. Can $A$ have complex non-real eigenvalues or not?

Comment: No, it can not.

Comment: Then, yes, it is the only possibility.

Comment: @José What about $$\varepsilon\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$ for $\varepsilon > 0$ sufficiently small to make whatever the matrix norm used be less than $1$?

Comment: @TheoBendit All right. I missed that possibility.